# Degree of splitting field over $\mathbb{F}_p$ not divisible by $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime and let $n\geq 1$ be an integer with $(n,p)=1$. Consider a polynomial of the form 
$$f(X)=X^d-\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}[X].$$ Suppose that $p$ does not divide $d$ and let $K$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Can we deduce that $[K:\mathbb{F}_p]$ is not divisible by $p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=1$, $d = p^p - 1$, and $\alpha = 1$. The roots of $f$ are precisely the nonzero elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^p}$, the degree $p$ extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$.